# How to use Apache resource by HTTPS in pacemaker?

Tags: https, apache2, high-availability, pacemaker, heartbeat

I have a problem when i change apache url to HTTPS. Before the change  every this working fine with http. Now my company need to use the Virtal ip by HTTPS. so that i didn't find any suitable tutorial about this issue.

i am working on debian 9. more details are below:

*/etc/apache2/status.conf*

```
 <Location /server-status>
 SetHandler server-status
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Require local
 </Location>
```

*/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
.....
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
Redirect "/" "https://ip_address/"
....
</VirtualHost>
```

**Error i received**

```
Failed Actions:
* Apache_monitor_0 on server1 'unknown error' (1): call=59, status=complete, exitreason='none',
    last-rc-change='Wed Sep  9 17:28:19 2020', queued=0ms, exec=71ms
* pgsqld_promote_0 on server2 'unknown error' (1): call=63, status=complete, exitreason='server1 is the best candidate to promote, aborting current promotion',
    last-rc-change='Wed Sep  9 16:57:25 2020', queued=0ms, exec=496ms
```

[pcs status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l6eq.png)

I tried to add resource like this but it didn't work

```
pcs resource create Apache ocf:heartbeat:apache  configfile=/etc/apache2/apache2.conf  statusurl="https://localhost/server-status"  op monitor interval=1min --force

pcs resource create Apache ocf:heartbeat:apache  configfile=/etc/apache2/apache2.conf  statusurl="http://localhost/server-status"  op monitor interval=1min --force
```

I created ssl file and remove status.conf file

/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

```
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

            DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            .....................
            <Location /server-status>
            SetHandler server-status
            Order Deny,Allow
             Deny from all
             Require local
            </Location>
................................

    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You have to make Apache listen on 443 and configure a TLS enabled `<VirtualHost *:443>` to handle those requests.

Comment: @EsaJokinen sorry for late reply. I config ssl file. add location status to my ssl file and remove status.conf. `pcs resource create Apache ocf:heartbeat:apache  configfile=/etc/apache2/apache2.conf  statusurl="https://localhost/server-status"  op monitor interval=1min `

It does't work yet